# Cкрипт для показа изображений с высоким разрешением

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, lightbox

Есть хороший скрипт `jquery-lightbox`. Но он не очень хорошо справляется с изображениями с высоким разрешением (речь идет о скриншотах различных текстов - такие изображения очень большие по высоте и соответственно файл изображения весит прилично). Такой скрипт очень долго грузит, и то и вообще не обрабатывает такие изображения. Посоветуйте пожалуйста альтернативное решение

Comment: Чтобы быстрей грузилось, нужно либо "жать" изображения на сервере и отдавать уменьшенную копию, либо сохранять изображения как progressive jpeg.

Comment: @RubaXa Жать изображения - не вариант, т.к. их уже набралось очень много и пересохранять каждое будет затратно по времени. Мне нужно подобрать именно скрипт

Comment: @Олег Серебряков, никакой скрипт вам не может, я даже ради интереса попробовал грузить изображение через xhr и на onprogress рисовать полученную часть через canvas, так это ещё медленней, чем обычная загрузка. На вашем месте сделал бы скрипт `/get-progressive-jpeg.php?file=...` который бы конвертировал и отдавал нужное изображение (результат можно кешировать).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Долго грузится? Так это может зависить и от скорости интернет-соединения (*изображения то не пару Кб весят*). Кроме того, популярные плагны содержат массу различных функций, которые может вам и не нужны для конкретной работы, но так же дают порой значительную нагрузку. Так же, плагины зачастую подгоняют размер большого изображения под размеры просматриваемой области экрана, что для вашей задачи не нужно. В такой ситуации, лично для меня, было бы одно единственное решение: написать самому такой плагин, содержащий только тот функционал, который нужен для поставленной задачи и не строчкой больше. Уверяю, что по сравнению с большинством готовых решений, ваш собственный вариант, может весить в разы меньше и обрабатывать изображения значительно быстрее.

P.S. Когда лень писать самому, использую [FancyBox 2](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/), но не тестировал его на изображениях очень большого размера.

Answer (score 1):

colorbox